# NVIDIA driver is not recognized when using Pytorch and Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pytorch

I have been trying to use Pytorch 0.4.0 in Python 3.5. I have an NVIDIA K40c GPU and CUDA driver version V9.0.176. However when I execute "torch.cuda.is_available()" it returns False. So, when I tried to define a Tensor it gives the following error:

```
AssertionError:
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
```

I reduced the code to only these three lines:

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("Is CUDA available? ",torch.cuda.is_available())
```

And the result is still False. However, if I comment the line:

```
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

it works fine. So it seems like there are some compatibility problems with matplotlib, any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I just figure it out, it seems like matplotlib is masking some functions of Pytorch, so If I revert the order of the import lines everything works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
print("Is CUDA available? ",torch.cuda.is_available())
```

So, now it returns True.